# How to reproduce Windows Chrome BAT files setup in macOS 10.15

Tags: macos, applescript, google-chrome

On Windows, Chrome is my primary browser.
I've developed a series of *.bat files on Windows that each open a series of tabs with specific URLs in Chrome:

```
@echo off
set BROWSER=chrome.exe
set WAIT_TIME=2
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\bat
start %BROWSER% -new-window "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month"
@ping 127.0.00.1 -n %WAIT_TIME% -w 1000 > nul
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://contacts.google.com/"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://voice.google.com/"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://hangouts.google.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://drive.google.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://maps.google.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://www.youtube.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://news.google.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://photos.google.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://one.google.com"
start %BROWSER% -new-tab "https://classroom.google.com"
```

How would I reproduce this functionality in macOS 10.15 using AppleScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open a generic URL from AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293777/how-do-i-open-a-generic-url-from-applescript)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312551/open-urls-in-new-chrome-window/312552#312552 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141702/open-a-new-safari-window-in-the-current-space-from-terminal-with-multiple-tabs

Comment: What's the purpose of the ping command?

Comment: the ping provides a necessary pause before the rest of the script is executed.

Comment: How about just `sleep 2` to pause for 2 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

As a shell script or directly in Terminal it can be done with

```
#!/bin/sh

open -a "Google Chrome" --args \
    https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month \
    https://contacts.google.com/ \
    https://voice.google.com/ \
    https://hangouts.google.com \
    https://drive.google.com \
    https://maps.google.com \
    https://www.youtube.com \
    https://news.google.com \
    https://photos.google.com \
    https://one.google.com \
    https://classroom.google.com
```

In AppleScript you can use

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month"
    open location "https://contacts.google.com/"
    open location "https://voice.google.com/"
    open location "https://hangouts.google.com"
    open location "https://drive.google.com"
    open location "https://maps.google.com"
    open location "https://www.youtube.com"
    open location "https://news.google.com"
    open location "https://photos.google.com"
    open location "https://one.google.com"
    open location "https://classroom.google.com"
end tell
```

Comment: In the original batch file all of the URLs open in a single Chrome windows. Were i to start another batch file with different URLs, they would all open in a SECOND Chrome window. Does both of your examples accomplish that? If not, how would I make sure each script file opens a new Chrome window?

Comment: @Quasaur Not directly, the idea mainly was to give you something to start with. The links in the comments point to other answers with parts of the puzzle you try to solve here.